# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 angular 4

Tags: angular, api, typescript, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I got this error  : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.azharcouncil.com/api/Employees/DeleteEmployee?id=11. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.  when trying to delete employee from the table .

data-storage.service.ts:

```
deleteEmployee(employeeId: any){
    let url = 'http://api.azharcouncil.com/api/Employees/DeleteEmployee?id='+employeeId;
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'applications/json')
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
return this.http.delete(url, options)
.map(resp => resp.json());

    }
```

employees.component.ts:

```
onDelete(employeeId: any){

  this.dataStorageService.deleteEmployee(employeeId).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
      return true;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.json().error);
          console.error("Error delete employes!");
          return false;
        }
       );
    console.log(employeeId);
   }
```

** when i tried this url in postman i can delete employee **

Answer (score 0):

I think request content type should be **application/json** also change headers should be append key for adding header options

```
deleteEmployee(employeeId: any){
 let url = 'http://api.azharcouncil.com/api/Employees/DeleteEmployee?id='+employeeId;
 let headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json') 
 return this.http.delete(url,{ headers: headers })
                .map(resp => resp.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);


}
```

Comment: can you post what you did

Comment: i changed deleteEmployee as u write . do u need to update my answer with your function ???

Comment: Yes boss can you please

Comment: @AyaAbdelaziz can you check my latest ans

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155422/discussion-between-robert-and-aya-abdelaziz).

Comment: you mean this error "headers.append need 2 arguments it give me error"

Comment: no i mean the error XMLHttpRequest cannot load api.azharcouncil.com/api/…. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.

Comment: what is your backend

Comment: i don't understand , can you explain ?